# Find all pairs that sum to a target value

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've been looking through this example which is a supposedly faster way of matching than using multiple loops. I've seen [an explanation here](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-two-sum-find-all-pairs-match-target-value/) but it makes absolutely no sense to me.

Can someone please break this down for me and what **`target - arr[i]`** is been used for?

```
const arr = [7, 0, -4, 5, 2, 3];

const twoSum = (arr, target) => {
  let map = {}
  let results = [];
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (map[arr[i]] !== undefined) {
      results.push([map[arr[i]], arr[i]])
    } else {
      map[target - arr[i]] = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return results;
}
console.log('twoSum = ', twoSum(arr, 5));
```

Comment: That's a neat solution! I would not have thought of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake in the explanation you linked to: where it says, "Our new key/value pair is `5: 5`. Our hash map now contains two entries: `{7: -2, 5: 5}`." The new key/value (and this is achieved correctly in the code) is `5: 0`.

To understand how it works suppose our array is `[2, 6, 3]` and the target is `5`. Once we see `2`, we'd like to know if the array has its partner that together sums to `5`.

```
x + 2 = 5
x = 5 - 2
x = 3
```

So we're looking for `3`. Now, the JavaScript map object allows us to efficiently retrieve a value if we know its key. So we set our key to `3` - this way if we see a `3` later, we can quickly respond. Remember that we haven't seen `3` yet. We're just setting the key to quickly alert us if we see it that we've seen its partner, `2`, already.

Now we continue along the array. We pass by `6` but there's no key `6` in the map so we add it to the map and continue. When we get to `3`, we say, "Aha!", the map having `3` is alerting us that we've seen its partner that together sums to  `5`. We push the result, `3` (the current `arr[i]`) and the value stored in the map under the `3` key (`map[arr[i]]`), which was the `2` we saw earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose target is t. Given a value x in the array, you want to know if there exists a value t - x in the array, in which case the sum is t - x + x = t.

So you go through the array, to mark the fact you see x in the array you mark the entry t - x in a map. Later when you encounter t - x in the array you check entry t - x in the map, and if it is populated then you know you previously saw x, which means you have the pair x and t - x. The way I just described it sounds like two loops through the array, but you can do these two things in just one loop and it works the same.

If a map entry is populated then you previously saw its pair value,  if not populated you mark the map to see if you encounter that pair value later.

Comment: Thanks Sean, but this makes less sense to me. t - x + x = t

Answer (score 1):

You could even make it more faster, without storing of the actual value, because you are looking for a two values and one is known, you know the other as well.

```js
const
    arr = [7, 0, -4, 5, 2, 3],
    twoSum = (arr, target) => {
        let map = {},
            results = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (map[arr[i]]) {                           // straight check
                results.push([target - arr[i], arr[i]]); // take delta
                continue;
            }
            map[target - arr[i]] = true;
        }
        return results;
    };

console.log('twoSum = ', twoSum(arr, 5));
```

Comment: Thanks Nina for a faster approach but I'm looking to understand how the example I posted works more than another approach.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is creating pairs by examining the currently processed item with previously seen items.

So, it requires a memory for the previously seen items, and that's why `map` factors into the solution.

Let's analyse the loop in the solution:

```
  for (let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if (map[arr[i]] !== undefined) {
      results.push([map[arr[i]], arr[i]])
    } else {
      map[target - arr[i]] = arr[i];
    }
  }
```

It's equivalent to the following:

```
  for ( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {

    // Any item in the array that's not in the memory
    // 1. should primarily be stored
    // 2. such that it's potential pair is stored as a key that's mapped to a value which is the item
    if ( map[ arr[ i ] ] === undefined ) {
      map[ target - arr[ i ] ] = arr[ i ];

      // Examine pairs only in iterations with odd numbered indices.
      // Why? - For the first iteration, the memory is empty...
      continue;
    }

    // this item’s pair is known, so store the pair in the result list
    results.push( [ map[ arr[ i ] ], arr[ i ] ] );
}
```